# custom view on iphone's native media player(MPMoviePlayerController)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, mpmoviewcontroller

I am building an application that implements a custom view on iPhone’s native media player. I want your help in deciding directions to lay this effort. At present I have find out that iPhone SDK doesn’t support APIs to customize media player.

I need these things in the player:

I would like to have custom views i.e. want to change all control buttons on player like Play/Pause, seek bar etc. The background of player will also need to be different. The player has to play audio or video file from local/remote location. Can i use MPMoviePlayerController if it can be customized (How to do it ??). However, any other third party player approved by iPhone which has an ability to download and play the media file from local/remote location is also fine.

It will be great to have an access to media player buffer so that it can be encrypted.

I have following questions:

1.Any help in building/customizing player.....

2.Do you see issues in signing of application?

3.Does Apple have any restrictions on customizing media player?

4.Any sample iPhone application where media player is customized

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You should go to the https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html and check for the custom labels and button added to MPMoviePlayer in a similar manner you can have your custom moviePlayer also.

Hope you fight and find your way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [3.2 SDK](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/movieSourceType) will help a little bit but you are still pretty limited in what you can customize.